# How can I add item in desktop menu/new file (right click on desktop)?

Tags: windows-7

I want to create new TXT file, but for some reason TXT file do not appears anymore when I click with right button on desktop, and go to 'NEW' (list of file types to create).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Detailing:**

1. Go to regedit
2. Open "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
3. Find '.txt' and click on it
4. Check if "(Default)" "Data" value is "textfile", if not, set it to "textfile"
5. Check if "ShellNew" path exists in '.txt', if not, create it
6. Check if "NullFile" string value exists in "ShellNew", if not, create it
7. Find 'textfile' on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" , if not exists, create it and set "(Default)" "Data" value to "Text Document" or other than you prefer
8. Go to desktop / right mouse click / Refresh to see your new item in 'New' list

**Basically 4 things are needed:**

1. .txt path with default value set as 'textfile'
2. ShellNew path into .txt path
3. 'NullFile' string value into ShellNew with no data
4. textfile path with default value as the description of file

Answer (score 8):

I saw these instructions [somewhere else](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/add-file-type-windows-7-context-menu/). They were really useful for me.

To Add an Item in “New” menu:

1. Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. Now expand “HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT” key.
2. Now look for the file type which you want to add in “New” menu, e.g. for adding MP3 file type look for .MP3 key.
3. Right-click on it and select “New -> Key” and give it name “ShellNew”.
4. In right-side pane, right-click and select “New -> String Value”. Give it name “NullFile” and press Enter.
5. Thats it. You’ll immediately get the file type entry in “New” menu.

Comment: Fantastic explanation and saved me a ton of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this post http://www.mediacollege.com/microsoft/windows/extension-change.html.

This should show you how to make a text file.

If this doesn't work you can add it in to the context menu by following these instructions
https://superuser.com/questions/629813/create-new-text-document-option-missing-from-context-menu